# why wont my custom built PC boot?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I turn it on and the lights turn on the fans are spinning but no picture turns up, and when it's on it'll sound like its powering down and then it'll fasten up again and it'll keep doing this.
My parts are:

Gigabyte h81m-hd3 motherboard
Corsair Atx 450 watt power supply
Intel pentium g3220 lga1150 CPU
I have not yet got my Graphics Card or Ram is this why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a PC without RAM and/or with any video output (motherboard's integrated or graphic card).

Wait for them and tell us.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget to power the ATX_12V_2X4, you can find it in the manual, and pc won't boot without RAM :)